# Column-by-row multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 matrices `A` (`mxn`) and `B` (`nxm`). I would to get matrix `C` (`nxmxm`), such that `C[i]=A[:, i].dot(B[i, :])`. In other words I would like to get matrix, where first element is dot of first column of `A` and first row of `B`, second element is dot of second column of `A` and second row of `B`, etc.
For example for such `A` and `B`

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, -1]])
B = np.array([[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]])
```

I would like to have such matrix:

```
C = np.array([[[4, 5], [0, 0]],
          [[12, 14], [6, 7]],
          [[24, 27], [-8, -9]]])
```

Is it possible without cycles? If not, is it possible for case `A = B.T`?

Comment: Won't `A[:, i].dot(B[i, :])` give  you a scalar instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk', A, B)

array([[[ 4,  5],
        [12, 14],
        [24, 27]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 6,  7],
        [-8, -9]]])
```

### EDIT

From your comment:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->jik', A, B)
```

will give you the desired shape of `C`

Comment: Thanks, did you mean: `np.einsum('ij,jk->jik', A, B)`? =)

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to get a 3D array of element-wise multiplications and not the matrix-multiplication( one that involves`sum-reduction`), you can use  [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to perform those multiplications in a vectorized manner, like so -

```
A.T[...,None] * B[:,None]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [524]: # Setup inputs
     ...: m,n = 200,200
     ...: A = np.random.rand(m,n)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(n,m)
     ...: 

In [525]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,jk->jik', A, B) #@Saullo Castro's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 27.1 ms per loop

In [526]: %timeit A.T[...,None] * B[:,None]
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop
```

Without any `sum-reduction` needed, direct `broadcasting` just saves us from a function call overhead and that probably is giving us some performance improvement here.